# How can you access elements from a fixed buffer in a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, fixed, unsafe

I am trying to do this, however it seems that nothing ever gets assigned to `BoneIDs` or `BoneWeights`, what is the proper way of doing this in C#?

```
public unsafe struct VertexBoneData
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    public Vector2 TexCoord;
    public fixed float BoneIDs[Bone.MaxBoneCount];
    public fixed float BoneWeights[Bone.MaxBoneCount];

    public float GetBoneID(int i)
    {
        return BoneIDs[i];
    }

    public void SetBoneID(int i, float value)
    {
        BoneIDs[i] = value;
    }

    public float GetBoneWeight(int i)
    {
        return BoneWeights[i];
    }

    public void SetBoneWeight(int i, float value)
    {
         BoneWeights[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of C# is this?

Comment: When compiled with .net core 3.0.100 the code works as expected. I set element 2 of BoneIDs by `.SetBoneID(2, 45.76f);` and `boneData.GetBoneID(2);` returned `45.76`

Comment: This is the correct way of implementing this by the way, accessing fixed fields without pinning, which is available starting with C# 7.3. (right from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers))

Comment: Please can you show a minimal repro that demonstrates the problem? On up to date compilers this should be fine, so a repro (I.e. a Main() method that we can run that shows exactly what you're seeing) would help. My guess is that you're actually seeing a copy-by-value semantic bug in your code (the code you haven't shown us) i.e. you're expecting a side-effect to show in a location, when you're actually updating an isolated **copy** of the struct

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, broadly speaking (personally I'd make the fixed buffer fields `private`, and add some range checks on `i`). I *strongly suspect* that what you're actually fighting with here is pass-by-value semantics, in which you're operating on an *isolated copy* of the value. Here's a fully runnable demo with your type "as is" (no changes) that shows everything working fine:

```cs
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        VertexBoneData data = new VertexBoneData();
        data.SetBoneID(3, 42F);
        Console.WriteLine(data.GetBoneID(3)); // writes 42

        // here's what I *suspect* you're doing
        SomePassByValueMethod(data);
        Console.WriteLine(data.GetBoneID(3)); // still writes 42, not 16

        // here's one way to fix that
        SomePassByReferenceMethod(ref data);
        Console.WriteLine(data.GetBoneID(3)); // writes 122
    }
    static void SomePassByValueMethod(VertexBoneData data)
    {
        data.SetBoneID(3, 16F);
    }
    static void SomePassByReferenceMethod(ref VertexBoneData data)
    {
        data.SetBoneID(3, 122F);
    }
}
public unsafe struct VertexBoneData
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    public Vector2 TexCoord;
    public fixed float BoneIDs[Bone.MaxBoneCount];
    public fixed float BoneWeights[Bone.MaxBoneCount];

    public float GetBoneID(int i)
    {
        return BoneIDs[i];
    }

    public void SetBoneID(int i, float value)
    {
        BoneIDs[i] = value;
    }

    public float GetBoneWeight(int i)
    {
        return BoneWeights[i];
    }

    public void SetBoneWeight(int i, float value)
    {
        BoneWeights[i] = value;
    }
}
static class Bone
{
    public const int MaxBoneCount = 4; // whatever
}

// just avoiding a dependency here, since I'm in a console exe
public readonly struct Vector3 { }
public readonly struct Vector2 { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Marshal Technique

```
        const int MaxBoneCount = 10;
        public struct VertexBoneData
        {
            public Vector3 Position;
            public Vector3 Normal;
            public Vector2 TexCoord;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = MaxBoneCount)]
            public float BoneIDs[];
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = MaxBoneCount)]
            public float BoneWeights[];
        }
```

Comment: This is a very different thing, and does not address the question which is specifically about accessing fixed buffers. Marshalling may be useful for p/invoke, but it doesn't relate to the question being asked.